# How to do automatic Google translation on page load?

Tags: translation

Is there any way to do automatic translation of a page where I have inserted that Google translation code? Normally user has to select a certain language and then Google translates it, but what I want is, after the page is loaded, it automatically does translation of a pre-defined language. Is there a way I can pass hard coded language name to Google javascript function which translates the document?

Thanks

Comment: Chrome does this automatically for me. Force your users to use it too :)

Comment: @leppie relying on the browser is very restrictive and hardly any mobile browsers offer this. Dolphin's language add-in is the only Android one that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the jQuery Translate library to do this before. Notwithstanding the general limitations of automated translation, it worked pretty well.

Take a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/wiki/General). You can use jQuery's selector mechanism to determine which content gets auto-translated on page load (something like `$('body').translate('english');`).